# Older dates are parsed as summer time, even if that is not true in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have a problem displaying a number of dates that are stored as longs.
I create the date objects with the constructor that takes the long argument, and then print the dates to a PDF file.

However, I have a problem with older dates, when running the program on Linux, compared to Windows.

Take this date: 25. april 1976 00:00:00 (long value: 199231200000L) for example. If I use a dateformater to display the date, it will display differently on Linux and Windows:

On Windows: 25. april 1976 00:00:00 CEST

On Linux: 24. april 1976 23:00:00 CET

The text rep. can be shown simply by running the following line:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance( DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL ).format( new Date( 199231200000L) )
```

I used [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to get the datevalue for this test:

```
new org.joda.time.DateTime().withDate( 1976, 4, 25 ).withTime( 0, 0, 0, 0 ).toDate().getTime()
```

Why does Windows show the output as CEST, and Linux as CET?

Comment: Which *exact* time zone are you in? (Where are you, physically?) What does `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` show on each of Linux and Windows? I suspect your two machines are differently configured...

Comment: It was midnight in Paris at that instant in time (CEST) but 23:00 in CET. So both results are correct and the output depends on the timezone of your machine.

Comment: Hm - the windows say europe/paris and the linux say europe/copenhagen. (i am in denmark) so that seems to explain it. But in timezone settings on the windows pc, there is no distinction between copenhagen and paris - they are grouped together into one (UTC+01)

Comment: We should also keep in mind the possibility to have different tzdb-versions on different machines. So check what your system timezones are (as Jon Skeet suggested) and check the versions (using TZUpdater).

Comment: Java does not manage its timezone data in Windows operating system (two totally different sets of data) so you cannot conclude anything from Windows.

Comment: Ok. My problem is then, that when users input their birthday, the date object is created on their machine and send to the server as a long. Doing this, and not also sending along the timezone info is no-go it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_France) has introduced summer time in 1976, but [Denmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Denmark) started DST in 1980. This explains the differences you observed so all is right except the fact that your system timezones are different. You should better use the same explicit timezone on both machines and not rely on the default timezone.

And by the way, if I look at the timestamps you use then I see no millisecond or just minute portion which makes me thinking if the intention was just to store a pure calendar date. If so then using timezones is in general dangerous as your problem clearly illustrates. Now Java-8 has the type `LocalDate` for this purpose - fortunately.

Comment: It seems that i have a bit of rewriting to do. Currently we create the date object clientside and send it to the server - without timezone info. The best practice it seems would be to create the date serverside.